# Why is there a Fairy shortage

Tags: the-fairly-oddparents

In the latest series of the Fairly odd parents that have Chloe why is there a fairy shortage, isn't there enough fairies to go around?

Answer (score -2):

I think if I could remember right from watching the THE FAIRLY ODDPARENTS  S10  E1 is because there is no more baby fairies born to then grow up and become fairy godparents but you know all they should of done is just wish for more baby fairies and some adult ones as well that could just fix the problem.